# CSP: multiple google uris and null?

Tags: security, null, content-security-policy

we started to use Content Security Policy quite recently and still have a lot of problems with it.

**1. blocked google URIs**
A lot of google URIs get blocked for different directives. For example:

```
"csp-report": {
    "blocked-uri": "https://www.google.co.za",
    "document-uri": "https://de.our-project.com/",
    "original-policy": "default-src https://de.our-project.com; script-src https://de.our-project.com data: https://*.our-project-test.com https://*.our-project.com https://*.our-project-stage.com https://s.yimg.jp https://www.google.co.jp https://p.dr.adingo.jp https://ajax.googleapis.com https://api.sovendus.com https://s.yjtag.jp https://data1.allo-pages.fr https://data1.mes-resultats.com https://*.yahoo.co.jp https://api.gutscheinconnection.de https://cdn.our-project-stage.com https://cdn.our-project.com http://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://maps-api-ssl.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://www.googleadservices.com https://*.justuno.com http://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.net https://pippio.com http://cdn.rawgit.com http://d.ratepay.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https://de.our-project.com https://*.our-project.com https://*.our-project-test.com https://www.sovendus.com https://cdn.our-project-stage.com https://cdn.our-project.com https://fast.fonts.net https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https://de.our-project.com data: https://*.our-project.com http://*.test.com https://*.test.com https://*.our-project-test.com https://www.google.com.co https://www.google.lt https://www.google.nl https://www.google.com.ua https://www.google.co.jp https://www.google.es https://www.google.co.uk https://www.google.dk https://www.google.co.il https://www.google.cz https://www.gstatic.com https://tap.rubiconproject.com https://sync.adap.tv https://d.agkn.com https://rudy.adsnative.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://*.sovendus.com https://gum.criterio.com https://wam.solution.weborama.fr https://pippio.com https://load.s3.amazonaws.com http://test-admin.devnet.nil https://a248.e.akamai.net https://er.criteo.com https://ibeu2.mookie1.com https://tags.bluekai.com https://s.thebrighttag.com https://elr.sfr.fr https://traffic.outbrain.com https://ext.ligatus.com http://www.seur.com https://*.rlcdn.com https://www.google.ie https://www.google.fr https://cdn.our-project-stage.com https://cdn.our-project.com http://pim.test.com https://admin.our-project-stage.com https://admin.our-project.com https://pim-cdn.test.com http://pim-cdn.test.com https://cms-cdn.test.com http://test.preview.denkwerk.com https://www.facebook.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps-api-ssl.google.com https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.de https://www.google.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://csi.gstatic.com https://maps.gstatic.com http://aa.agkn.com https://aa.agkn.com http://login.dotomi.com https://login.dotomi.com http://emailretargeting.com https://emailretargeting.com https://p-eu.acxiom-online.com http://global.ib-ibi.com https://global.ib-ibi.com http://loadus.exelator.com https://loadus.exelator.com http://i.liadm.com https://i.liadm.com http://rc.rlcdn.com https://cm.g.doubleclick.net https://secure.insightexpressai.com https://e.nexac.com https://stags.bluekai.com https://pm.w55c.net https://um.simpli.fi https://dt-secure.videohub.tv https://c.bing.com https://b97.yahoo.co.jp; font-src https://de.our-project.com data: https://cdn.our-project-stage.com https://cdn.our-project.com https://fonts.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src https://de.our-project.com https://profile.justuno.com https://www.justuno.com https://profilebak.justuno.com http://d.ratepay.com; media-src https://de.our-project.com; object-src https://de.our-project.com https://d.ratepay.com; child-src https://de.our-project.com https://bid.g.doubleclick.net https://www.youtube.com https://www.justuno.com; frame-src https://de.our-project.com https://bid.g.doubleclick.net https://www.youtube.com https://www.justuno.com; frame-ancestors https://de.our-project.com ; form-action https://de.our-project.com https://www.computop-paygate.com https://*.paypal.com https://www.sandbox.paypal.com; manifest-src https://de.our-project.com;",
    "referrer": "https://de.our-project.com/",
    "violated-directive": "img-src https://de.our-project.com data: https://*.our-project.com http://*.test.com https://*.test.com https://*.our-project-test.com https://www.google.com.co https://www.google.lt https://www.google.nl https://www.google.com.ua https://www.google.co.jp https://www.google.es https://www.google.co.uk https://www.google.dk https://www.google.co.il https://www.google.cz https://www.gstatic.com https://tap.rubiconproject.com https://sync.adap.tv https://d.agkn.com https://rudy.adsnative.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://*.sovendus.com https://gum.criterio.com https://wam.solution.weborama.fr https://pippio.com https://load.s3.amazonaws.com http://test-admin.devnet.nil https://a248.e.akamai.net https://er.criteo.com https://ibeu2.mookie1.com https://tags.bluekai.com https://s.thebrighttag.com https://elr.sfr.fr https://traffic.outbrain.com https://ext.ligatus.com http://www.seur.com https://*.rlcdn.com https://www.google.ie https://www.google.fr https://cdn.our-project-stage.com https://cdn.our-project.com http://pim.test.com https://admin.our-project-stage.com https://admin.our-project.com https://pim-cdn.test.com http://pim-cdn.test.com https://cms-cdn.test.com http://test.preview.denkwerk.com https://www.facebook.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps-api-ssl.google.com https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.de https://www.google.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://csi.gstatic.com https://maps.gstatic.com http://aa.agkn.com https://aa.agkn.com http://login.dotomi.com https://login.dotomi.com http://emailretargeting.com https://emailretargeting.com https://p-eu.acxiom-online.com http://global.ib-ibi.com https://global.ib-ibi.com http://loadus.exelator.com https://loadus.exelator.com http://i.liadm.com https://i.liadm.com http://rc.rlcdn.com https://cm.g.doubleclick.net https://secure.insightexpressai.com https://e.nexac.com https://stags.bluekai.com https://pm.w55c.net https://um.simpli.fi https://dt-secure.videohub.tv https://c.bing.com https://b97.yahoo.co.jp"
}
```

But we don't even have this URI in our site. It's the same for a lot of other google URIs.
Does someone know why we get these violations and how to resolve them?

**2. blocked-uri: null**
There are a lot of

```
"blocked-uri": "null"
```

parts in our violation log. It's always the font-src directive, that takes action with this.
I've read about it being empty but couldn't find anything about "null".
Can anybody explain to me, how this happens?

**EDIT**

I've read some more into it now and it seems like google AdWords and analytics (?) are the reasons for my first problem.

Solution for this:
Either add ALL 200 or so google domains to your CSP or allow ALL image sources (or at least the specific protocol)

To my second problem:
It seems like "null" replaced the empty string. But all I found was about the script-src directive being violated, which either means the report is about inline javascript or an eval() function.
Both is not the case for me as the font-src directive is being violated.

If I find out something new, I'll edit the post again.

Comment: While I think this is on-topic here and a good question, you may try asking it in [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) too to possibly invite some more answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

**1. blocked google URIs**
Either add ALL 200 or so google domains to your CSP or allow ALL image sources (or at least the specific protocol)

**2. blocked-uri: null, violated-directive: font-src** 
It seems like browser extensions cause this error. Namely lastpass. We tried it and on login the CSP threw the violation.

Hope this helps some people in the future.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you for taking the time to follow up with the answer when you found it yourself. You have saved me some time, that's for certain!